# OAuth 2.0 authentication for mobile client

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am developing an app using node.js which will also have an mobile client. I am looking to make the authentication using OAuth 2.0. I have my own external server which will do client validation and generate tokens. Please help me know as to how can i achieve this using OAuth2orize or any other really good module.

Answer (score 0):

Read their documentation, its quite simple and easy to implement for client side validations.
[Oauth 2.0 Client Side validation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)

Comment: Similarly Im having end point urls. How can I make it work using OAuth2orize node module?